# Java - Messaging Framework

Tags: java

I would like to test a distributed algorithm that supposed to run over multiple servers (each server running the same code and logic). The end-points will communicate by broadcasting messages to each other.

For the purpose of pre-testing the algorithm I thought of developing a single process application where each end-point is simulated by a single thread.

Is there any framework that provides something similar in terms of just defining how many threads, implementing the messages and the code that will be executed by each thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find that Akka does what you need. [Akka](http://akka.io/) uses actors as the implementation of business logic - these actors react to events produced by other actors.

Akka provides this API and deals with the coordination of the actors - while `Thread`s must be used underneath, the developer doesn't have to deal with them.

The final benefit in the context of your question is that Akka can be distributed over multiple machines - I don't believe this change from single-machine to multiple-machine involves much if any modification of the program. I assume you need to ensure your events implement `Serializable`.